Trying to change the default page break numbering format
You provided an answer on the below post, I wanted to ask if this should work on Wordpress posts or pages, Im trying to do something similar for posts but I added your code to functions.php and it didn't change anything so I just wanted to check if this was suitable for posts, in short im trying to change the default page break numbering in the urls to use a custom word found from each pagebreak title from the same post.
post pagination names, not numbers

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
